# Python Matplotlib: Color graph bygroup

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to edit the colormap of the below code such that each grouped ID, has the same color. Currently, all the lines have a different color which has historically been fine (though not preferred), however I now have enough lines that colors are overlapping. Simply applying the colormap to the plot function seems to always return the same color. I have also tried changing the Matplotlab default color scheme without success as it seems to default to the same count of colors. I have not found a way to change the color per id_group at all nor increase the color count to add more colors to the scale. Any ideas?

Also I am relatively new to Matplotlib and any useful sites which have great example code for common yet complicated problems would be hugely appreciated.

```
df = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['id', 'name', 'mod', 'ms', 'avg'], value_vars=bp)
newdf = df.loc[(df['id']==747) & (df['mod']==79189) | (df['id']==748) & (df['mod']==79189) | (df['id']==165) & (df['mod']==79189)].reset_index()
newdf['test'] = newdf.value/newdf.avg
newdf.drop('index', axis = 1, inplace = True)
newdf.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace = True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for title, group in newdf.groupby('id'):
    group.groupby('ms').plot(x='variable', y='test', ax=ax, label = title)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.078, 1))
    plt.tight_layout(rect=[0,0,1.5,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the question does not show any of the attempts that have been made in any of the directions of selecting a color, taking a color from a predefined colormap or changing the colorcycle. Without that it's really just asking for ways to select colors for different plot. There are numerous questions on this already; I marked as a duplicate of one that has several different answers to chose from.